# Writing Code in the Application Xcode

Tags: c#, c, xcode

Hey, I'm pretty new at this. So, I just downloaded Xcode from developer.apple.com and I'm currently getting to know the application. Getting to the point, my question is, where do you type the code?

Answer (score 0):

Double click on `main.m (or .c or .cpp)` or open the file into new window.
XCode has usually split windows. The upper side for the files, the lower side for editing. But this is depending on how you setup XCode.

Comment: By the way, if you can't see any main files, then you have to create a new XCode project first. (File Menu:New Project)